# Deploy Apache Camel on(with or without spring boot) on wildfly server

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, wildfly

We have use case where we need to develop integration on Apache camel.
However, from deployment point of view we have Wildly server where so far we have deployed varous Java spring boot Microservices.

Also, wehave another environment where these Java spring boot service are deployed on Openshift inside JBoss EAP conatiner.

Now, quuestion is how can I deploy apache camel routes/jar in similar way on Wild fly or Joss.

Few options , I can think of but not sure hows it possible.Need technical guidance.

Options
1. Create camel jar and deploy on Widlfly- I dont know how it works.
2. Create apache camel integration using spring boot . As per documentation ,it will work . my question in how it will be deployed on widlfly or open shift.
Also, can I use spring DSL in that?

Comment: You can create a Spring Boot WAR deployment. That's it. Works on every app server.

Comment: Btw. there is also a WildFly Subsystem https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel and this also exists for EAP

Comment: Yeah using the wildfly-camel is the recommended way for JBoss EAP, such as in the official Red Hat Fuse product where you can use Fuse on EAP and other runtimes.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share reference links. Which I can follow. The material online is too confusing. Also. Here my use case is bit different. I want to create jar or war which can be deployed on both. Development or SIT environment we are using wildfly. But in Uat and prod environment we are using open shift with jboss eap container for each pod. Plz suggest on  this line

Comment: @SimonMartinelli can I write this print boot War using spring Dsl or I have to write in java DSL. Any reference links you can sharw will help

Comment: @ClausIbsen considering my comments below about our deployment enviroment. Can you please also suggest the best approach for development and packing. Are we doing right to use spring boot or shall we just use apache camel jar and deploy on wildfly and jboss eap or tomcat?